# Select first row of each group by group in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, group-by

I would like to get the first row of each group with the smallest "differenz" value of the group like I tried here. How can I achieve that?

This is my query

```
SELECT 
    ae.vpid AS aeVpid,
    ae.EreignisDat AS aeEreignisDat, 
    be.StichtagDat AS beStichtagDat,
    ABS(DATEDIFF(day, ae.EreignisDat, be.StichtagDat)) AS differenz
FROM 
    AEGE AS ae 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    BEST AS be ON ae.VPID = be.VPID
WHERE 
    ae.EreignisDat <> be.StichtagDat
ORDER BY
    aevpid, differenz ASC, beStichtagDat DESC
```

I get this result:

[image: this]

where "beStichtagDat" is variable and depending on the first two attributes "aeVpid" and "aeEreignisDat"

I tried some group by's on some attributes and subqueries with a `min()` on "differenz" and I also tried the `row_number()` over the groups but I could not manage to get it done

Comment: Don't use column numbers for ORDER BY. This has been poor practice for more than 20 years, if not 30.

Comment: `row_number()` with `partition by` will be the answer, but I don't see what determines your groups, since columns 1 and 2 are the same for the entire set, and 3 seems unique.

Comment: Thank you. I edited the order by with numbers

Comment: "I tried some group by's on some attributes and subquerys ..."  So where's this query???  We don't see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`row_number()` + `partition by` is probably the way to go here, but this is still incomplete because the question doesn't show anything about how to split up the groups:

```
SELECT  aeVpid, aeEreignisDat, beStichtagDat, differenz
FROM (
    select
        ae.vpid as aeVpid,
        ae.EreignisDat as aeEreignisDat, 
        be.StichtagDat as beStichtagDat,
        abs(datediff(day, ae.EreignisDat, be.StichtagDat)) as differenz,
        row_number() over (partition by ???? order by abs(datediff(day, ae.EreignisDat, be.StichtagDat))) rn

    from AEGE as ae 
    left join BEST as be on ae.VPID = be.VPID
    where ae.EreignisDat <> be.StichtagDat
) t
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY aevpid, differenz, beStichtagDat DESC
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It helped me a lot and I could manage the get it done